# SQL to get data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write an sql query to show the wing_name, sister_name and nurse_name by joining tables.

```
SELECT WING.WING_NAME, SISTER.SISTER_NAME, NURSE.NURSE_NAME
  FROM NURSE
      JOIN SISTERNURSE ON NURSE.NURSE_ID = SISTERNURSE.NURSE_ID
      JOIN SISTER ON SISTER.SISTER_ID = SISTERNURSE.SISTER_ID
      JOIN WING ON WING.SISTER_ID = SISTER.SISTER_ID
WHERE WING.WING_NAME = '*';
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?

I need to pull Nurse_name from the Nurse table, which is linked to another table called Sister by the foreign key Sister_ID, this table is then linked to another table called Wing which has the foreign key Sister_ID. SisterNurse is just a bridge table with the foreign keys Nurse_id and Sister_id.

I have four values in wing_name. Would I just put WING.WING_NAME= 'SPARROW', 'LORIKEET', 'MACAW', 'KINGFISHER'; ?

Table structure:

**Sister table** - Sister_id (primary key), sister_name, sister_surname, sister_contactnumber, sister_salary

**Wing Table** - wing_id(primary key), wing_name, number_of_rooms, sister_id(foreign key)

**Nurse table** - Nurse_id(primary key), nurse_name, nurse_surname, nurse_contactnumber, nurse_salary

**SisterNurse table** - SisterNurse_ID(primary key), Sister_id(foreign key), Nurse_id(foreign key)

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?  That would be useful information.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are joining `SISTERNURSE` table; If you are not going to display any records from it

Comment: Your query looks syntactically OK.  The only weird thing I see is the `where` condition because to get any record from that query you have to have a `Wing_Name` with value `*`.

Comment: I need to pull Nurse_name from the Nurse table, which is linked to another table called Sister by the foreign key Sister_ID, this table is then linked to another table called Wing which has the foreign key Sister_ID. SisterNurse is just a bridge table with the foreign keys Nurse_id and Sister_id.

Comment: table structure: Sister table - Sister_id (primary key), sister_name, sister_surname, sister_contactnumber, sister_salary Wing Table - wing_id(primary key), wing_name, number_of_rooms, sister_id(foreign key) Nurse table - Nurse_id(primary key), nurse_name, nurse_surname, nurse_contactnumber, nurse_salary SIsterNurse table - SIsterNurse_ID(primary key), Sister_id(foreign key), Nurse_id(foreign key)

Comment: @Avidan it looks like an intermediate table between `Nurse` and `Sister` (many to many)

Comment: @CrApHeR How would I select all the values from wing_name then? I tried WHERE WING.WING_NAME = ANY but that didn't work.

Comment: The error I receive is no rows selected

Comment: You want to get only the records with values in the Wing table and it associated values?

Comment: I need to show the each value of the wing_name along with the nurses and sister who operate within that wing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have commented on another answer below; I am adding those names in In Operator.

Please check the output:

```
 SELECT WING.WING_NAME, SISTER.SISTER_NAME, NURSE.NURSE_NAME
      FROM NURSE
          JOIN SISTERNURSE ON NURSE.NURSE_ID = SISTERNURSE.NURSE_ID
          JOIN SISTER ON SISTER.SISTER_ID = SISTERNURSE.SISTER_ID
          JOIN WING ON WING.SISTER_ID = SISTER.SISTER_ID
    WHERE WING.WING_NAME in ('SPARROW', 'LORIKEET', 'MACAW', 'KINGFISHER');
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just missing 'in'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would I avoid suppression of the repeating wing and wing sister name? as there are many nurses in one wing but only one wing sister

Comment: I couldn't get your question :( Can you explain me?

Comment: don't worry, Ive got it!

Answer (score 0):

use a proper value to wing_name and all other sql queries are seems to be ok. You enter a proper value for wing_name and execute the query. Check if it is still giving the same error or not.

Comment: so i have four values in wing_name would i just put WING.WING_NAME= 'SPARROW', 'LORIKEET', 'MACAW', 'KINGFISHER'; ?

Comment: It needs to be generated from one piece of SQL so I can't just enter one value